# I have a problem with my code for a discord bot, it keeps showing the same error

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I followed a youtube video for this code and it just doesn't work, this is the part of the code where the error is:

```
    @client.command(name='queue', help='This command adds a song to the queue')
async def queue_(ctx, url):
    global queue

    queue.append(url)
    await ctx.send(f'`{url}` added to queue!')

@client.command(name='play', help='This command plays songs')
async def play(ctx):
    global queue

    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(queue, loop=client.loop)
        voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' %e) if e else None)

    await ctx.send('*Now playing:* {}'.format(player.title))
    del(queue[0])
```

And this is the error it shows:

```
    Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\moham\Desktop\musicbot.py", line 102, in play
    player = await YTDLSource.from_url(queue, loop=client.loop)
NameError: name 'queue' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'queue' is not defined
```

please help...

Comment: Did you actually define queue above? That's nowhere in your code fragment & quite relevant

Comment: doesn't "Global queue" define it?

Comment: No, Global means you can use a variable defined outside of your function's scope. You have to define it first. By using Global you're never giving it a type, so there wouldn't be a way for python to know what Queue is supposed to be (list, int, ...)

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define the `queue` variable. You need to define it above your functions to be able to use it.

```
queue = []

@client.command() # rest of your code
```

Comment: I did that and it said "Command raised an exception: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: That sounds like a different question with a different error traceback. You can always ask another question on stackoverflow.

Comment: That's not related to my answer or your question, and without a proper traceback I can't help you with that. If my answer fixed your current issue you should mark it as correct. Feel free to post a new question with the new error.

Comment: Yea fair enough! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

as an answer said, define `queue = list()`, but change `player = await YTDLSource.from_url(queue, loop=client.loop)` to `player = await YTDLSource.from_url(queue[0], loop=client.loop)` and add `queue.pop(0)` after `voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' %e) if e else None)`, so it removes the song its now playing from the list.